# Function setting number to zero by itself?

Tags: c++, histogram

My function is somehow changeing a number I pass it to zero, even if I set an arbitrary number to the variable, the function changes it to zero?
What is going on? How is that even possible?

Variables are defined here

```
int count,i,binnumber,*histo,tempmax,tempmin;

float *data,y,temp,binwidth;

tempmin = floor(temp);
binnumber = ceil(sqrt((count-1)));          
//out_stream << binnumber << endl;          
binwidth = abs(tempmax-tempmin);
binwidth = binwidth/binnumber;  

for (int i=0; i<count; i++)
{
    data[i] = data[i] - tempmin; 
    out_stream2 << data[i] << "\n";
}
func.histogram(data ,histo, binwidth, binnumber);       //create array for histogram use
int holder = 0;
```

and this passes to the function here which changes it to zero all the time

```
void DSP1D::histogram(float *data,int *histo, float _binwidth, int _binnumber)
{

    binwidth = _binwidth;
    cout << "binwidth is: " << binwidth <<  endl;
    binnumber = _binnumber;
    for( int i = 0; i < count; i++ )
    {
        binnumber = data[i]/binwidth;

        binnumber = binnumber / binwidth ;
        //binnumber = floor(binnumber);
        //cout << binnumber << "bin one\n" ;
        histo[binnumber] = histo[binnumber] + 1 ; //possibly import sorted numberlist and place sorted numbers in appropriate bins
    }
}
```

binwidth is the value that becomes zero and we use

`cout << "binwidth is: " << binwidth << endl;`

to check the value,
help please?

Comment: What number is becoming zero? Where is `binwidth` defined? Is it global? What type is it?

Comment: And how do you determine if it becomes zero? If the optimizations are on, debugger watches can report misleading values.

Comment: Sorry, binwidth becomes zero 
and we use 
`cout << "binwidth is: " << binwidth <<  endl;` to check the value

Comment: What is the value of `_binwidth`? I asked about the type above because if it's not a float or double, then a type conversion could potentially cause rounding and make it 0 when you don't expect it. And I asked about its scope (global or local) because you may be using a different variable than you think. Also, have you tried stepping in the debugger and checking the value? Print formatting may be causing it to display rounded, even though it's got another value.

Comment: What is the definition of `binwidth` and all the other relevant class members? I would guess binwidth is zero simply because `_binwidth` passed into the method is zero.

Comment: `_binwidth` is used to pass `binwidth` into the histo function, `binwidth` is a `float` 
It is defined in no other class

Comment: @user1118321 and @uesp already suggested you print the value of `_binwidth` inside the function. Did you try that?

Comment: Yes, I did and I showed it returns zero also. In the shell.

Comment: So the problem isn't in `DSP1D::histogram`, you are passing a zero to the function. Start looking at the call site instead.

Comment: @Tyberius - You don't show where you set the values of `temp`, `count`, and `data`. If `count` and `data` aren't handled correctly, the loop could easily overwrite other values.

Comment: `temp` is derived by calculating the minimum value , `tempmin` is taken by taking the floor of this, neither of these are a problem.
`data` is read in from a file and `count` is taken by counting how many numbers are in the file, none of these are the problem, they're all read into the function just fine, it's `binwidth` that gets changed into a zero by the function. It's called as the same type it's defined as, it reads it as the right number before and after the function, the function is doing something to it.

Comment: I would suggest making a small test program which duplicates the issue as you haven't given us enough information to be able to see what the problem might be without guessing at what you're doing or trying to do. Chances are that in the process of making the test case you'll find the problem anyway and, if not, you can post that small test case here for more help.

Comment: If it actually is changing _during the function call_ then either you are corrupting the call stack or your code is haunted. Could you be linking against an old object file? Try rebuilding everything.

Comment: It's easily possible, (to start with, your code has stars in it).  What hardware is this running on, (DSP1D?), what other hardware has access to this memory space and how many threads run through this code?

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell from your code - there are a number of issues:

```
int count,i,binnumber,*histo,tempmax,tempmin;

float *data,y,temp,binwidth;

tempmin = floor(temp);
binnumber = ceil(sqrt((count-1)));          
//out_stream << binnumber << endl;          
binwidth = abs(tempmax-tempmin);
binwidth = binwidth/binnumber;
```

1) You are using temp, tempmax, count all without assigning them first.  That means they are going to have some random value in them (whatever value was already in memory where each variable was placed).  What are they supposed to be, did you leave out code in between?  If count is less than one, you would have to use some sort of imaginary numbers in your program as well, because of sqrt((count - 1)), and also binnumber would be random (if the program doesn't stop running because this basic cmath sqrt function doesn't deal with imaginary numbers)

2) tempmin is being set to the floor of temp even though temp as not been set to anything, so tempmin will also be random.

3) binwidth is being set to the absolute value of tempmax - tempmin, both which have random values, so binwidth will also have some random value.

4) if you get to the line where binwidth = binwidth / binnumber, realize that because you are using all ints, for the division, you will return an int (basically the remainder will be dropped), so you would need to cast one side, like this:

binwidth = (float)binwidth / binnumber, or binwidth = bindwidth / (float)binnumber, or binwidth = (double)binwidth / binnumber, or bindwidth = binwidth / (double)binnumber.

Plus - of course if binnumber is 0 (and it could be here, because it's random, you could get a crash), you might want to do something like this:

if (binnumber) binwidth = (double)binwidth / binnumber; - or some sort of solution

if (binnumber) is the same as if (binnumber != 0), in C and C++, all non-0 values are true and 0 is false.

So yeah, basically there are a lot of problems with your code, and I would suggest making sure you don't use variables in an expression or formula without assigning them to beforehand, and try printing out the value of binnumber at various places before the code to.

Wait a second, you didn't even allocate for *data, it is possible to do what you did to data, your computer will often allow it to a point, as long as length is not large, is there a big missing piece in bewtween from your code?  Where are your variables being initialized?